# Change reading path from url to local file in Python

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I tried the style transfer from https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_arbitrary_image_stylization on Google colab and i would like to read a local path from Google colab like '/content/a.jpg' instead of a url from other website what should i modify the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

You can use your Google drive directory as an external drive.

Then lets say there is a file called a.jpg in your google drive main folder, you can point to it like this,

```
data_dir  = '/content/drive/MyDrive/a.jpg'
```

if it is in a picture directory withing your drive, you can try this

```
data_dir = '/content/drive/MyDrive/pictures/a.jpg'
```

Then change the load_image function, to this,

```
@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def load_image(image_path, image_size=(256, 256), preserve_aspect_ratio=True):
  """Loads and preprocesses images."""
  # Load and convert to float32 numpy array, add batch dimension, and normalize to range [0, 1].
  img = tf.io.decode_image(
      tf.io.read_file(image_path),
      channels=3, dtype=tf.float32)[tf.newaxis, ...]
  img = crop_center(img)
  img = tf.image.resize(img, image_size, preserve_aspect_ratio=True)
  return img
```

Then you can try,

```
load_image(data_dir)
```

Comment: yes i know i can use this but i dont know how to modify the code since its seems that its correlated

Comment: you mean you dont know how to find your file from that ?

Comment: @MoJiebu I uploaded an example of how to access your file.

Comment: i know how to find the file but i dont know how to modify https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/tf2_arbitrary_image_stylization to do the same thing

Comment: sorry, i have updated my answer again, this should work

Comment: in the later part i used style_images = {k: load_image(v, (style_image_size, style_image_size)) for k, v in style_urls.items()} anything that should I change?

Comment: did you change the definition of the code yet?